# Import C++ dll failed in Python

Tags: python, windows

Following document in "Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter", I created a VC project, and a dll file was successfully created with name "spam_d.dll"

Main code was

```
static PyObject *
spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;
    sts = system(command);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}

static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    {"system",  spam_system, METH_VARARGS, "Execute a shell command."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);
}
```

Then I typed following command in python:

> > > import spam
> > >       [39003 refs]
> > >       spam.system("pwd")
> > >       /SVN/Python/PCbuild
> > >       0
> > >       [39005 refs]

It looks working correctly. 
But when I rename the dll name from spam_d.pyd to spam.pyd. Python can't find the module.

```
>>> import spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named spam
[39005 refs]
```

From the first case, it looks python could setup relationship between "import spam" and "spam_d.pyd" correctly.

How did python know "spam" module is "spam_d.pyd", but not "spam.pyd"?

And is there any documents mention it.

Comment: "..The initialization function must be named initname(), where name is the name of the module..", but I'm not sure that this is the source of your problem.

Comment: "the name of the module" is spam_d or spam?

Comment: I have to admit that I quickly read the question, but you quickly read the documentation ;-).
"can only import a module spam if its initialization function is called initspam(), and it should call Py_InitModule() with the string "spam" as its first argument.." and "By convention, it lives in a file called spam.c or spammodule.c. The output file should be called spam.pyd (in Release mode) or spam_d.pyd (in Debug mode)."

Answer (score 1):

The python tries to link against a debug library with suffix _d.pyd, since it's a Debug build. To link aganist spam.pyd, you need a Release build.